# problem with installation of ggplot2 (and rlang) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang, install.packages

I have problem with installation of `ggplot2` in `R`. I am using `Windows10` and my `R` version is `4.0.3` (I can't update it because I don't have admin permissions).
What I did:

1. I tried install ggplot2 `install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)`
2. Get error during installation (first one):

`'loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])': namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required`

3. I downloaded `1.0.6` verson of `rlang` from [LINK](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/) and installed manually
4. I get error:
   `Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'`

I have no idea how to solve it? I read `Rtools` but I can't install it without admin permissions.

Comment: Try starting R and then running `install.packages("rlang")` as the first command. That should update that package. And then try to install ggplot2.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Steps:

1. For starters i had to remove (uninstall) all ggplot2 related libraries
   then i tried to install ggplot2
2. I was getting a message as in the main thread that the `rlang` library is required at least version `1.0.6` so I downloaded the exact version `1.0.6` from CRAN and this `r-release`. NOTE: Downloading newer versions didn't help, it had to be this particular one
3. then I got a message that the `lifecycle` library is missing in the minimal version and I also installed the minimal with `r-release`

Following this path, I finally got `ggplot2` installed. I have no idea why it did that, but it does